# convert string property from api to JSON object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i'm making a call to an api which returns data to the front end in this format

```
{ name: 'Fred', 
data: [{'name': '"10\\" x 45\\" Nice Shirts (2-pack)"', 'price': '$30.25'}]
}
```

the data property is return as a string and i'm trying to use JSON.parse(response.data) to get it as as array so i can use `*ngFor` to do iteration but i'm always getting an error

```
Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 2
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 2 (at zone.js:1262:1)
    at JSON.parse
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your backend is not returning a valid json. It should be:

```
{"name": "Fred", "data": [{"name": "\\"10\\\\\\" x 45\\\\\\" Nice Shirts (2-pack)\\"", "price": "$30.25"}]}
```